# ld returned 1 exit status - c

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

Im trying to compile reboot.c binary for android but i keep getting following error:

```
/home/pedja/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-   linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: ./obj/local/x86/objs/reboot   /reboot.o: in function main:jni/reboot.c:49: error: undefined reference to 'android_reboot'
/home/pedja/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: ./obj/local/x86/objs/reboot  /reboot.o: in function main:jni/reboot.c:51: error: undefined reference to 'android_reboot'
/home/pedja/android-ndk-r8d/toolchains/x86-4.6/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-linux-android/4.6/../../../../i686-linux-android/bin/ld: ./obj/local/x86/objs/reboot/reboot.o: in function main:jni/reboot.c:47: error: undefined reference to 'android_reboot'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/x86/reboot] Error 1
```

reboot.c

```
 #include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "android_reboot.h"
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ret;
    int nosync = 0;
    int poweroff = 0;
    int flags = 0;

    opterr = 0;
    do {
        int c;

        c = getopt(argc, argv, "np");

        if (c == EOF) {
            break;
        }

        switch (c) {
        case 'n':
            nosync = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':
            poweroff = 1;
            break;
        case '?':
            fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-n] [-p] [rebootcommand]\n", argv[0]);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    } while (1);

    if(argc > optind + 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: too many arguments\n", argv[0]);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if(nosync)
        /* also set NO_REMOUNT_RO as remount ro includes an implicit sync */
        flags = ANDROID_RB_FLAG_NO_SYNC | ANDROID_RB_FLAG_NO_REMOUNT_RO;

    if(poweroff)
        ret = android_reboot(ANDROID_RB_POWEROFF, flags, 0);
    else if(argc > optind)
        ret = android_reboot(ANDROID_RB_RESTART2, flags, argv[optind]);
    else
        ret = android_reboot(ANDROID_RB_RESTART, flags, 0);
    if(ret < 0) {
        perror("reboot");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "reboot returned\n");
    return 0;
}
```

android_reboot.h

```
#ifndef __ANDROID_REBOOT_H__
#define __ANDROID_REBOOT_H__

__BEGIN_DECLS

/* Commands */
#define ANDROID_RB_RESTART  0xDEAD0001
#define ANDROID_RB_POWEROFF 0xDEAD0002
#define ANDROID_RB_RESTART2 0xDEAD0003

/* Flags */
#define ANDROID_RB_FLAG_NO_SYNC       0x1
#define ANDROID_RB_FLAG_NO_REMOUNT_RO 0x2

int android_reboot(int cmd, int flags, char *arg);

__END_DECLS

#endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're showing that you've declared `android_reboot` however your link fails because the implementation of that function cannot be found. Declaration is not the same as definition... declaration satisfies the compiler, but only implementation satisfies the linker. Where is this function implemented?

Comment: I have no idea, i dont know anything about c. I took this from android source, i need it for my java application

Comment: The source you took this from either included some other source for `android_reboot` (which you need to pull in), or stated what library to include in your link (which you would need to add to your build script), or is incomplete.

Comment: I'm probably asking to much, but can you point me in the right direction. This is the source:   https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/master/toolbox/   I really don't want to go learn c from start just because of few binaries i have to compile in c

Comment: Ouch. Big ouch. C isn't something where spending 5-15-50 minutes can be enough for most practical purposes.

Comment: I know that, i just dont want to spend days-mounths learning other programing language just for one program that i dont even have to write just to compile. But thanks anyway

Comment: @pedja assuming you've actually pulled down the Android source package, "grep -R android_reboot ." (from inside its directory) might help to find its implementation. I hope you realize though that unless your apk is signed using the system's platform key, you probably will not have the privileges to reboot the device.